# I'm looking for a blend mode that gives 'realistic' paint colors. (Subtractive)

Tags: opengl, colors, shader, rgb, color-blending

I've been looking for a blend mode to (well ...) blend two RGB pixels in order to build colors in the samw way that a painter builds them (i.e: subtractive).

Here are quick examples of the type of results that I'm expecting:

> CYAN + MAGENTA = BLUE
>   CYAN + YELLOW = GREEN
>   MAGENTA + YELLOW = RED
>   RED + YELLOW = ORANGE
>   RED + BLUE = PURPLE
>   YELLOW + BLUE = GREEN

I'm looking for a formula, like:
    dest_red = first_red + second_red;
    dest_green = first_green + second_green;
    dest_blue = first_blue + second_blue;

I've tried with the commonly used 'multiply' formula but it doesn't work; I've tried with custom made formulas but I'm still not able to 'crack' how it should work. And I know already a lot of color theory so please refrain from answers like:

> Check this link: [http://the_difference_betweeen_additive_and_subtractive_lighting.html](http://example.com)

Note: Check that your blend method works with YELLOW + BLUE = GREEN and YELLOW + RED = ORANGE

Comment: check this link http://forums.xkcd.com/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=42927 lol.  Especially the post that says "Sorry, you can't mix RGB colors with an exact physical  match to real world painting.  RGB is an additive model of frequencies."  and then the poster says "your best option is to convert the color into another space, mix them, and convert back.  HSV or HSL are good choices for artists."

Comment: Thanks Richard, very illustrative post, however the guys there don't seem to know really well what they're talking about. For example, OP wants to achieve Yellow + Blue = Green while at the same time Red + Green = Yellow, I don't know if that's a mistake or not but definitely not what I'm looking for.

Comment: The way Photoshop does this is basically to treat CMY pixels as inverted. So pure cyan would be <0, 1, 1> (instead of <1, 0, 0> like you'd expect). Blue would be <0, 0, 1>. It turns out that's the same way of representing the color as RGB.

Answer (score 1):

The CMY color space, which addresses this kind of subtractive blending, is basically the inverted RGB space. You can add colors in CMY space and convert them back into RGB.

```
CYAN (100 CMY) + MAGENTA (010 CMY) = (110 CMY) = (001 RGB) = BLUE
CYAN (100 CMY) + YELLOW (001 CMY) = (101 CMY) = (010 RGB) = GREEN
...
RED (100 RGB) + YELLOW (001 CMY) = (011 CMY) + (001 CMY) = (012 CMY) => (0 0.5 1 CMY) = (1 0.5 0 RGB) = ORANGE
RED (011 CMY) + BLUE (110 CMY) = (121 CMY) => (0.5 1 0.5 CMY) = (0.5 0 0.5 RGB) = PURPLE
```

As you see, you have to normalize the color, if there are components with values greater than 1.

---

I just realized that the last addition (YELLOW + BLUE) does not work with this model. I leave the answer here, though. Maybe it can help you. That's probably because your examples may contain an inconsistency. If CYAN+YELLOW=GREEN, it is very unlikely that the same GREEN can be generated with BLUE+YELLOW.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt there is one best answer for this question. If you only want substractive color space, [CMY(K)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMYK) could be enough. If you however want to create something similar to ArtRage rather than pure Photoshop, implementing your own blending curves is a must for realistic effects.

Comment: Is there an example implementation of those blending curves somewhere?